# Handling PostTooLargeException in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, redirect, handler, laravel-5.5

I am trying to handle `PostTooLargeException` in my Laravel 5.5 application.

When I trying to upload too big file through my form I receive `PostTooLargeException` which I successfully catch in `app\Exceptions\Handler.php`, but on that step I would like to redirect user back to the page with form and show an error message.

I wrote following code:

```
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
...
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
    ...
        if($exception instanceof PostTooLargeException){
                    return redirect()->back()->withErrors("Size of attached file should be less ".ini_get("upload_max_filesize")."B", 'addNote');
            }
    ...
    }
}
```

As a result I was redirected to the proper page but without any message and `ViewErrorBag` was empty.
Did I something wrong with that redirection?

Thank you a help!

Comment: Do you check inside your `blade` if there are some `Session` messages? Like `@if(Session::has('foo') {{ $foo }} @endif`

Comment: @Tarasovych Yes, I did, and I do not have any session messages. Now I see, that on a moment when `PostTooLargeException` appears, session is not started yet, so I need to start a session somehow... `\Session::start()` and `session_start()` did not help me, but I did not dig to much in that way yet...

Comment: hmm, very strange that `Session` has't started...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ViewErrorBag` is empty because session is not start in the `Handler`. Solution was previously described by [@Talinon](https://laracasts.com/@Talinon) at [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/exception-handler-for-posttoolargeexception)

To make session available in the `Handler` class, I moved `\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class` from `$middleware` to `$middlewareGroups` array at the `App/Http/Kernel.php`

My updated `$middlewareGroups` array looks like:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class, // <<< this line was added
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,

        ],
        ...
];
```

Comment: it seem worked, but an error thrown ```PHP Warning: POST Content-Length of 8978294 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0```. Based on your answer, I add ```\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class``` into ```$middleware``` and it worked. Thanks